# Is "Actes de JADT" same as JADT conference? Where to download Actes de JADT publications?

Tags: publications

A paper is cited in another paper as:

> An Arabic morphological analyzer and part-of-speech tagger
>
> M Altabba, A Al-Zaraee, MA Shukairy
>
> Actes de JADT, 50, 2010

You can check the reference at https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/F13-1029

And Google Scholar shows that the paper is published at Actes de JADT: https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=sdbpUkYAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra

But I could not find it at JADT 2010 files: http://lexicometrica.univ-paris3.fr/jadt/jadt2010/tocJADT2010.htm#Contents

I am confused. Is Actes de JADT the same as JADT conference?
If they are different, where to download the publications of Actes de JADT? And if they are the same, why I cannot find the above mentioned paper at the contents of JADT 2010?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://lexicometrica.univ-paris3.fr/jadt/index.htm) I would understand "Actes de JADT" to mean the proceedings of the JADT conference. Typically, a conference and its proceedings go hand-in-hand. Someone might informally state that they have had a paper accepted or published in "Conference X", but a formal citation would later point to "Proceedings of Conference X" or similar (the title can vary). While I have no direct prior knowledge of JADT, I'd expect it to be the same case here.

Now, clicking through the google scholar link to the actual [document](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Muhammad_Altabba/publication/330825156_An_Arabic_Morphological_Analyzer_and_Part-Of-Speech_Tagger/links/5c55715792851c22a3a2dc9f/An-Arabic-Morphological-Analyzer-and-Part-Of-Speech-Tagger.pdf), it appears to be a thesis (or project report as you state in the comments), not a published article. However, there's [this paper from Actes de JADT 2010](http://lexicometrica.univ-paris3.fr/jadt/jadt2010/allegati/JADT-2010-1033-1044_090-Kammoun.pdf) by different authors, but with a quite similar title. I think that other works may have miscited one of these, or that Google Scholar might have misinterpreted some citations. Anyway, given that your title is not listed in the Actes de JADT 2010 Table of Contents, I think you can safely assume it wasn't somehow published there.

Comment: Thanks for your time trying to answer the question. Actually, I am the same person and that was the report of my graduation project to get the bachelor degree. It was not a thesis. Even though I unintentionally did it even good enough that made 3 other papers to cite it as a Master Thesis. And even 1 cited it as a Ph.D. thesis. I did not publish it at Acts de JADT but I found people and Google Scholar are referencing it as it was! And this what made me curious to know what is happening.

Comment: And could you make it more clear to me about "Is Actes de JADT the same as JADT conference?" In other words is there a reason to say that some paper is published at "Actes de JADT" (proceedings of the JADT conference)? And not to say published at "JADT". Is there any difference between publications listed under "Actes de JADT" and "JADT"?

Comment: @MuhammadAltabba Very well. Note that if it was the report required to get the bachelors degree, it can be called a bachelor thesis. The cover page of that document actually states that it is  "A Thesis Presented...". It doesn't seem to state the degree level explicitly, so perhaps that explains others citing it as a Masters or PhD thesis. Anyway, I think you can safely assume that your report was not published in Actes of JADT given its absence from the table of contents.

Comment: @MuhammadAltabba For the question in the second comment, please note that I'm in a very different field, and have no direct knowledge about JADT. However, I'd guess this is like most conference papers. You might informally say that your paper was published in Conference X, but a formal citation would point to e.g. "Proceedings of Conference X".

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. I was a beginner doing my bachelor and I tried to mimicate what they write at a higher educational degree. But I should have used the word "report of a project" not "a thesis". Because the university was asking for a project and along with the project a report of it.